# UITableView Cell Titles Don't Populate

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

So basically I have a problem, i have never used storyboard before and it's completely frustrating me but i'm trying to learn it. I have multiple navigation controllers where i embedded all of them in a single tab bar controller. (See Pic 1)![Pic 1][1]

However, I can't get any type of data to populate for the cell.textLabel.text

I'm sure it's an easy fix, but like I said I'm new to storyboards.

My code is below, but first here is what i have set in storyboard:

TabBarController is set to Initial View Controller. 
Class is set to default. All Sizes are set to inferred. 
Triggered Segues are set to all 4 Navigation Controllers

For my Publications Navigation controller (The first one i'm trying to get to populate data) I have the class set to default.
Triggered Segues are set to root view controller which in this case is title root view controller
Presenting Segues as a relationship from tab bar controller

The Root View Controller of that Navigation controller i have the class set to "PublicationsTableViewController"
Table View Content is set to Dynamic Prototypes
Outlets:
dataSource is Root view Controller (the one it's in)
delegate is Root View Controller (the one it's in)

Table View Cell 
has no outlets or segues yet
Style is custom
Reuse Identifier is "Cell"

In PublicationsTableViewController my code is:

.h

```
@interface PublicationsTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *mainpubArray
```

.m

```
@interface PublicationsTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation PublicationsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"PUBLICATIONS";

_mainpubArray = @[@"Animals", @"Buildings", @"Vehicles", @"Entertainment"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [_mainpubArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [_mainpubArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

![enter image description here][2]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if the Array has values, That might cause some error. Also check if the number of rows returned are correct.

Comment: I entered NSLog(@"%2d", [_mainpubArray count]); into the viewDidLoad and it returns 6 @NKB

Comment: but that number is right i just didn't type in the other two items in the snippet above. I do have 6 items.

Comment: Have you set up the tableview delegates properly via the storyboard

Comment: @Flexicoder I'm not sure i think thats why i'm here. never used storyboard. normally i would just say tableview.delegate = self; but using storyboard is new to me. Not sure whats the issue. is it because i embedded it?

Comment: In storyboard, select one of the tables, then using the inspector on the right check that the delegates are linked, in the same way you would of checked when using XIB's

Comment: @Flexicoder i added a picture (See pic 2) referencing delegates/dataSource

Comment: looks good, so not that then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning 0 as the number of sections...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 0;
}
```

Should be...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;  //Or how many sections you need
}
```

Comment: I hate you..but i love you. Thanks mate. Can't believe i overlooked that. So maybe i hate myself.